# Password protect any file in WordPress

Tags: uploads, htaccess, password

I have found that password protection with .htaccess & .htpasswd files is the only way to protect any WordPress file.

I wanted to make few of my media files accessible by specific username and their password. To do this I did not find any specific WordPress plugin.

I am thinking to design a WordPress plugin to password protect any media file in the following way:

1. When user go to 'Media' and opens a file, then there will a option to protect the file
2. On clicking I will ask username and password to protect file and my plugin script will make the respective entries in .htaccess & .htpasswd files

I want to know, should I go for this task of new plugin or do you already know any other plugin with this functionality.

Comment: If someone wants to open it, he can and will. Welcome to the Internet.

Comment: Hello @user1719322 - Welcome to the WordPress Development community! Could you clarify your question a little further? Where would you like users to enter such a password, and how would you like to store/update that password? What have you tried thus far? Check out the "[ask]" page in our [help] for more tips on writing good questions.

Comment: That said, it seems like [basic `.htpasswd`/`.htaccess` authentication](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htaccess/ht/password_1_file.htm) would fulfill your needs.

Comment: @bosco solution article suggested by you great. What do you think is there any plugin, that can help to do this easily.